# remove time from dates when shown on highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

how can i remove the time from the date when shown on the highchart.the data (dates) are received from a twitter get request and saved into an array.

```
    for (var i in array) {
        dateArray.push(array[i].date);
            }  
    highchart(dateArray);
```

an example of date shown on the graph: Sat,04 Aug 2012 19:35:02 +0000

Comment: "Sat,04 Aug 2012 19:35:02 +0000" is how it shows in the chart or this is how you get from twitter?

Comment: both.is how i get from twitter and how are shown on graph. xAxis: {
   categories: dateString
  },

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on your comments

You can first convert the string to a date object, and then format the date object to your liking using SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d yyyy");
String formattedDate = format.format(new Date(array[i].date));
dateArray.push(formattedDate);
```

You can find various date formats @ http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: I think `Date.toString` function does not take any parameter.

Comment: you got me...
Too much of C# these days :|
Fixed above

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have two options:

1. Only pass in the day value of the time for your categories. Involves processing on the backend.
2. Pull your data as-is and convert to Javascript time format, make your xAxis datetime type, set up your tickInterval to be one day, and run your chart.

Without know what your data looks like, what you are plotting on the yAxis, or what your expected outcome is it is really hard to say.

I recommend to go with option #2 because this is time based data.